simultaneous transactions
Good afternoon, dear friends. I apologize. I'm faced with a serious question and I can't find the answer anywhere.
There is a smart contract for exchanging coins, for example, usdt for eth. The balance is usdt 15,000 and the balance is eth 5.
What happens if 2 transactions from two addresses are sent at the same time, for an exchange of 15000USDT?
Someone does not get enough. What will happen to these transactions? Will one pass? Or will both fail?


The validator decides the order of transactions when they produce a block
The validator pick the order based on MEV
The transaction the validator does not like will get rejected


Thank you so much for your reply. Please tell me, can timestamp and expiration somehow affect the priority of a transaction?

The question does not matter, because validator is free to use whatever rules they like. They will always choose the rules that will maximize profit for themselves, at the expense of you, as a user.

Thank you for the answers. I use the TRON network. There is a fixed fee for the production of the block. The MEV network does not use. As far as I understand, TRON validators skip the transaction that entered the network earlier.
